# Pasting to Excel after window.getSelection() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, getselection

I would like to copy the HTML from a div to Excel. The code below copies the content of my div:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>    
  <body>
    <div id="copyString"></div>    
    <script>
      var copyString = "Col1\tCol2<br>1\t2";
      $('#copyString').html(copyString);
      window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(document.getElementById('copyString'));
    </script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

When I paste the code in to Excel I'm expecting to have this result:

[image]

However I have this result:

[image]

It is weird because when I paste it first in to Notepad++ and then to Excel I don't have the issue. Could you tell me why is it not working like expected please?

Comment: Fro the behaviour you see it seems the `/t` escape sequence doesn't work when pasted. Try using commas instead to see if a more CSV-live format works, eg `var copyString = "Col1,Col2<br>1,2";`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it doesn't work neither. Excel displayes the commat instead of spliting the cells